# How to stop Azure Message Session Handler from timing out when listening for messages?

Tags: azure, timeout, azure-webjobs, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues

Below is my synchronous implementation of the IMessageSessionHandler interface. One problem I have is that when there are no messages in the queue the InitializeReceiverSync method will repeatedly run until the web job ungracefully times out in Azure, resulting in a failure. On the other hand if there are messages in the queue to be read, once they are read, the session closes and the program exits.

What is the best way to exit the method if there are no messages in the queue?

```
    public void ReceiveMessagesFromAzure()
    {
        int i = 0;
        while (i < 4)
        {
            var QueueName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["QueueName"];
            var connectionString = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Microsoft.ServiceBus.ConnectionString"];
            CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
            InitializeReceiverSync(connectionString, QueueName, cts.Token);
            i++;
        }

    }
    public void InitializeReceiverSync(string connectionString, string queueName, CancellationToken ct)
    {
        var receiverFactory = MessagingFactory.CreateFromConnectionString(connectionString);
        ct.Register(() => receiverFactory.Close());

        var client = receiverFactory.CreateQueueClient(queueName, ReceiveMode.PeekLock);

        client.RegisterSessionHandler(
            typeof(SessionHandler),
            new SessionHandlerOptions
            {
                MessageWaitTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5),
                MaxConcurrentSessions = 1,
                AutoComplete = false
            });

    }

    class SessionHandler : IMessageSessionHandler
    {

        AzureRepository ar = new AzureRepository([queueName], [connectionString]);
        void IMessageSessionHandler.OnMessage(MessageSession session, BrokeredMessage message)
        {
            ar.ProcessMessage(message);
        }

        void IMessageSessionHandler.OnCloseSession(MessageSession session)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Session closed");
            Environment.Exit(0);
        }

        void IMessageSessionHandler.OnSessionLost(Exception exception)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(exception.Message);
            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit");
        }
    }
```